# Get CookieContainer with Webclient and Set this CookieContainer

Tags: c#, http, post, cookies, windows-phone-8

I work with the Webclient class and first I do a Post request with this and send login data to a server. And from this Post I want the CookieContainer, but how can I get this?
And After this I want to send a Get request to the same server and Use now the CookieContainer from the Post request. So I first want to get the cookie and second I want to set it. But how dies it work with the Webclient class? I found something like this:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private readonly CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.CookieContainer = m_container;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

But with using this class, I can't use the CookieContainer from the Post request also in the Get request.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
  private static CookieContainer m_container = null;

  protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
  {
    WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
    if (m_container != null)
    {
        webRequest.CookieContainer = m_container;// will be called from the second time onwards
    }
    else
    {
      webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();// First time
      m_container =  webRequest.CookieContainer; // Copy the container after the post is success
    }
    return request;
  }
}
```